# How to put <h1>, <h2> tags in legend of <p:fieldset>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Using a library of components like Primefaces speeds up development with JSF (and has many other advantages!).

From a Search Engine Optimization (SEO) perspective, however, components are not ideal. For example, in Primefaces I can use a sort of panel called a [fieldset](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/panel/fieldset.xhtml):

```
<p:fieldset legend="Title of my panel">
    <p>
       Content of my panel
    </p>
 </p:fieldset>
```

The title of the panel (set with the attribute "legend" of the fieldset) would have been a good candidate to put inside a `<h2>` or `<h3>` tag, because they are important subtitles in the page and search engines rely on these tags for their indexing. Using the `fieldset` component seems to prevent using `<hn>` tags in the titles of these components?

Is there a way I can have both? Primefaces components like `fieldset` with `h1`, `h2`, `h3` tags for the titles of these components?

Comment: Also if you are interested in SEO for your JSF app you may want to look at: https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/584 with example here: https://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/ViewResourceHandler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p:fieldSet` has a facet for the `legend`. So you can do:

```html
<p:fieldset>
    <f:facet name="legend">
        <h3>Title of my panel</h3>
    </f:facet>
    <p>Content of my panel</p>
</p:fieldset>
```

See also:

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/fieldset?id=legend